# How to obtain View objects on screen with AccessibilityService on android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to create an android app that provides an accessibility service that when activated, it captures the whole screen content and the views inside it.
I looked a lot in the Android documentation and I got the understanding that I can get the AccessibilityNodeInfo that has a lot of info about the screen content.
The problem is that I want to have the Views themself.
The AccessibilityNodeInfo provides className, packageName, childs, parents, lots of booleans regarding is it focusable, checkable and it even provides the text of the View. And I say, if I can read the View's text, why shouldn't I know its width, height, location, font ect.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AccessibilityNodeInfo.ExtraRenderingInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.ExtraRenderingInfo) to get TextSize or LayoutSize(width,height) of the View. This is added in API 30.

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo mNodeInfo;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            int height=mNodeInfo.getExtraRenderingInfo().getLayoutSize().getHeight();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I want to have the Views themself

That is not possible, sorry.

> if I can read the View's text, why shouldn't I know its width, height, location, font ect.?

Because those things have limited value for accessibility, presumably. If you can provide a detailed description of how knowing those things will allow you to improve the lives of those with physical challenges, [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Even then, though, the most likely case is that Google would add that sort of detail to the existing accessibility objects.